# "To give someone space"

Tags: translation, idiom

I was looking for an equal word to say "to give someone space" in Korean but I couldn't find it. Even in Naver. I did find one, it's : 공간을 주다 but I'm not sure if it's the one I'm looking for.

How do you say "to give space to someone" in Korean?

What I mean by giving someone space is like giving them some me-time or letting them to be just alone, doing what they like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, “공간을 주다” wouldn't work, as the “space” you mean is a bit of a metaphor Korean doesn't have. Korean might use the word “time” instead (interesting, don't you think?). There are several I can think of for those senses of the word. I'm not sure if these are what you wanted, though.

---

### A time to think about one's relationship ― 생각할 시간

“Should we keep this relationship on or let it go?”

> 생각할 시간을 갖다
>
> To have a graceful time to think (about one's relationship)
>
> 생각할 시간을 주다
>
> To give (someone) a graceful time to think (about one's relationship)
>
> 생각할 시간을 갖게 하다
>
> To let (someone) have a graceful time to think (about one's relationship)

### A graceful time to make a decision ― 생각할 시간

“Take your time, and go with what's good for you.”

> 생각할 시간을 갖다
>
> To have a graceful time to think, **to make a decision**.
>
> 생각할 시간을 주다
>
> To give (someone) a graceful time to think, **to make a decision**.
>
> 생각할 시간을 갖게 하다
>
> To let (someone) have a graceful time to think, **to make a decision**.

---

### Me-time ― 혼자만의 시간

“From time to time, I have a me-time for my own happiness.”

> 혼자만의 시간을 갖다
>
> To have a me-time, during which they can do whatever they want to, alone.
>
> 혼자만의 시간을 주다
>
> (Nope! Rarely used.)
>
> 혼자만의 시간을 갖게 하다
>
> To let/have (someone) have a me-time, during which they can do whatever they want to, alone.

---

### Physical space ― 자리

> 자리를 내주다
>
> To give (someone) a place by leaving the place for them <sub>(Let me know if it sounds off.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

A : 주가가 내려가고 있어. 팔까 ?

Stock price is lowering. How about selling ?

B : 생각좀 하께.

I need some time of thinking about it.

Alternatives for B :

가만히 있어봐 Stay without any move

잠깐만 Just a moment

기다려 봐 Wait and see (what I encounter in my head)